# Write C code in Text Block in XAML for Windows Phone 8

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

I am writing a book for learning C language in the form of a Windows Phone 8 App.
I will be writing some C Code examples in the book. I am writing the content of the chapter inside a text block. Here is the sample:

The code that I have written is:

```
<TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Let's start the programming by writing a small program which prints a message on the screen. The program would be like this:" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="629" Width="410" FontSize="20" Margin="0,10,0,-22" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>
```

After the line **The program would be like this:** , i want to write a C program formatted as:

```
#include<stdio.h>
void main()
{
   printf("Welcome to C programming");
}
```

How do I go about writing this in XAML, is there any way by which I enter this formatted text in XAML and it appears with all the formatting.

Comment: See `TextBlock` and `Run` elements

Answer (score 1):

You can use `RichTextBox`.

Example:

```
<RichTextBox Name="richTB" IsReadOnly="True">
    <RichTextBox.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Paragraph}">
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0"/>
        </Style>
    </RichTextBox.Resources>
    <FlowDocument>
        <Paragraph>
            <Run Text="#include" Foreground="Gray" />
            <Run Text="&lt;stdio.h&gt;" Foreground="Red" />
        </Paragraph>
        <Paragraph>
            <Run Text="void " Foreground="Blue" />
            <Run Text="main()" Foreground="Black" />
        </Paragraph>
        <Paragraph>
            <Run>{</Run>
        </Paragraph>
        <Paragraph Margin="10,0,0,0">
            <TextBlock>
                 <Run Text="printf(" Foreground="Blue" />   
                 <Run Text='"Welcome to C programming"' Foreground="Red" />                           
                 <Run Text=");" Foreground="Black" />
            </TextBlock>                                                               
        </Paragraph>
        <Paragraph>
            <Run>}</Run>
        </Paragraph>
    </FlowDocument>
</RichTextBox>
```

Comment: Rich text box is not available as a control for windows phone app.

Answer (score 0):

This may be what you are looking for

```
<StackPanel Background="White">
            <TextBlock>
                <Run Text="#include" Foreground="Gray" />
                <Run Text="&lt;stdio.h&gt;" Foreground="Red" />
            </TextBlock>
            <TextBlock>
                <Run Text="void " Foreground="Blue" />
                <Run Text="main()" Foreground="Black" />
            </TextBlock>
            <TextBlock Foreground="Black">{</TextBlock>
            <TextBlock>
             <Run Text="     printf(" Foreground="Blue" />   
             <Run Text='"Welcome to C programming"' Foreground="Brown" />                           
             <Run Text=");" Foreground="Blue" />
            </TextBlock>
            <TextBlock Foreground="Black">}</TextBlock>
        </StackPanel>
```